# How to convert an associative array in python?

Tags: python, for-loop

I am really new to python and I can't find any information about this. I have an associative array `item`,

```
item['id'] = 0
item['title'] = 'python'
```

I want to validate the contents of item but I dont want to use the index name like `'title'` but just have a for loop and iterate over all entries in item regardless of their meaning. Something like that

```
for a in range(0, len(item)):
    print (item[a])
```

Any ideas  or suggestions?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In Python, associative arrays are called [dictionaries](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict).

A good way to iterate through a dict is to use [`.iteritems()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.iteritems):

```
for key, value in item.iteritems():
    print key, value
```

If you only need the values, use [`.itervalues()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.itervalues):

```
for value in item.itervalues():
    print value
```

As you learn more about Python and dictionaries, take note of the difference between `.iteritems()`/`itervalues()` (which returns an iterator) and `items()`/`values()`(which returns a list (array)).

**In Python 3**

`.iteritems()/.itervalues()` have been removed and `items()/values()/keys()` return iterators on the corresponding sequences.

```
for key, value in item.items():
    print(key)
    print(value)
```

Comment: Note: in Python 3, these become `.items()` and `.values()` (and a newcomer might have chosen to download Python 3).

Comment: @Thomas Good point, thanks. I'll leave the answer as is for now since Python 2 seems to still be the default for many distros, and I think it's important for newcomers to recognise the difference between iterators/generators and lists.

Comment: You're welcome. I'll add that many users may be on Windows, where there's no default Python at all. No idea if that applies to this questioner, but it's worth considering.

Answer (score 6):

There are three ways to iterate a dictionary:

```
item = {...}
for key in item: # alternatively item.iterkeys(), or item.keys() in python 3
    print key, item[key]

item = {...}
for value in item.itervalues(): # or item.values() in python 3
    print value

item = {...}
for key, value in item.iteritems(): # or item.items() in python 3
    print key, value
```

Comment: Ahh.. I missed the your first example in my answer. That's useful since it shows that iterating a `dict` gives you keys. +1